# Show a hidden div depending upon two radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

In my html form, I have two sets of radio buttons and depending upon its response, I am displaying a hidden `div`

My HTML code:

```
<div class="input-quest">Question 1</div>
<div class="input-resp">
<input onClick="question_1_response_yes();" type="radio" name="button1" value="Yes" checked /><label>Yes</label>    
<input onClick="question_1_response_no();" type="radio" name="button1" value="No" /><label>No</label>
</div>  

<div class="input-quest">Question 2</div>
<div class="input-resp">
<input onClick="question_2_response_yes();"  type="radio" name="button2" value="Yes" checked /><label>Yes</label>   
<input onClick="question_2_response_no();"  type="radio" name="button2" value="No" /><label>No</label>
</div>  

<div id="response-q1-yes-q2-yes" style="display:none;">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="input-quest">Question 3</div>
        <div class="input-resp"><span><input  class="textbox" id="q3" name="q3" type="text" value=" " /></span></div>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="response-q1-yes-q2-no" style="display:none;">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="input-quest">Question 4</div>
        <div class="input-resp"><span><input  class="textbox" id="q4" name="q4" type="text" value=" " /></span></div>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="response-q1-no-q2-yes" style="display:none;">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="input-quest">Question 5</div>
        <div class="input-resp"><span><input  class="textbox" id="q5" name="q5" type="text" value=" " /></span></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="response-q1-no-q2-no" style="display:none;">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="input-quest">Question 6</div>
        <div class="input-resp"><span><input  class="textbox" id="q6" name="q6" type="text" value=" " /></span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am able to display hidden div depends upon a single radio button using onclick function like

```
function question_1_response_yes()  {
$('#response-q1-yes-q2-yes').slideDown("fast");
$('#response-q1-yes-q2-no').slideUp("fast");
$('#response-q2-no-q2-yes').slideUp("fast");
$('#response-q1-no-q2-no').slideUp("fast");
}
```

But I need to display the hidden textboxs depends upon two set of radio buttons selections like

```
question-1 yes and question-2 yes ---> display div `response-q1-yes-q2-yes`
question-1 yes and question-2 no ---> display div `response-q1-yes-q2-no`
question-1 no and question-2 yes ---> display div `response-q1-no-q2-yes`
question-1 no and question-2 no ---> display div `response-q1-no-q2-no`
```

I have to display hidden div ONLY after the two radio buttons selections. How can do this

[**FIDDLE SETUP**](http://jsfiddle.net/a2fbp/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have globally scoped variables to store the response for each question. Set the value of these when the radio button is selected, then call a function that evaluates (Checks) the values of the response variables and sets the visiblility of your divs accordingly.

I have updated your JSFiddle to demonstrate this:
http://jsfiddle.net/a2fbp/10/

```
var q1Response = '';
var q2Response = '';

function question_1_response_yes()  {
    q1Response = 'y';
    CheckResponses();
}

function question_1_response_no()   {
    q1Response = 'n';
    CheckResponses();
}


function question_2_response_yes()  {
    q2Response = 'y';
    CheckResponses();
}


function question_2_response_no()   {
    q2Response = 'n';
    CheckResponses();
}

function CheckResponses()
{
    // 1) First, hide all questions, taking us to our default state
    $('#response-q1-yes-q2-yes').hide();

    // 2) Check responses - Show the appropriate text box
    if (q1Response == 'y' && q2Response == 'y')
    {
        $('#response-q1-yes-q2-yes').slideDown("fast");
    }

    /* Add if statements here similar to 2) above for other scenarios */
}
```

Comment: I need to show the hidden div only after both radio button click ? how can I make that..your code will load on first radio button click itself

Comment: I have updated the fiddle and code in my post to suit the behaviour you need - Apologies, the original code was incorrect. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response.. I got the idea from your code and made the correction myself...

Answer (score 2):

Some jQuery Deferred fun (see http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/ ):

http://jsfiddle.net/a2fbp/4/

```
var dfd = $.Deferred();
var radios = {};

// use the change event too, think about keyboard users
$('input[type="radio"]').on('click change',function(){ var $t=$(this);
    dfd.notify(
        $t.attr('name'),
        $t.attr('value').toLowerCase()
    );
});

dfd.progress(function( name, value ){
    radios[ name ] = value;
    //console.log( name, value );
    var id = 'response-q1-'+(radios.button1||'')
                    +'-q2-'+(radios.button2||'');
    //console.log( id );

    // you should use some nicer selector here, like a common class
    $('[id^="response-q1-"]').each(function(){ var $t=$(this);
        $t[ $t.attr('id') === id ? 'slideDown' : 'slideUp']("fast");
    });
});
```

Okay, actually you could use plain functions instead of notify/progress :)

Comment: Thanks, but  this code not working when I putting it on my actual site ?

Comment: My original answer uses the same html code you provided, in the updated one I modified it. And I just fixed my answer a little bit. Or maybe you are not putting the `$('input..').on('click...)` part into a `$(function(){ /*here*/ });` wrapper

Comment: Cleaned up example, changed the deferred thing to plain function + added the $(...) wrapper: http://jsfiddle.net/a2fbp/6/

Answer (score 0):

I would do this a totally different way, first by making just one javascript function that handles all of the radio buttons.

```
$("input[type=radio]").on("click",questionResponse);
```

Then, work out the logic to evaluate all buttons from one function:

> ```
> // untested psuedo code to get you thinking...
> function questionResponse(e){
>     var _name = e.target.name;
>     var _val = e.target.value;
>     var isQuestionOne = (_name.indexOf("1") != -1):true?false;
>       var isTrue = (_val == "Yes");
>     if(isQuestionOne){
>         if(isTrue){
>             // question one and "Yes"
>             $('#response-q1-yes-q2-yes').slideDown("fast");
>             $('#response-q1-yes-q2-no, #response-q2-no-q2-yes, #response-q1-no-q2-no').slideUp("fast");
>             // here, add in whatever else you want to show or hide
>             // if (question 2 is yes...), etc...
>         } else {
>              // question one, and "No"
>         }
>     } else {
>          // question 2
>         ...do this for the remaining combinations...
>     }
>  }
> ```